# How to use Jquery picnet Table filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, plugins, filter

I have copied picnet Table filter script files in my grails app js directory. Then I have included `jquery.cookie.js picnet.jquery.tablefilter.js` then, below lines to include filter for my table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()   {                                                                
$('#logDisplayTable').tableFilter();});
</script>
```

In table header field of column to be filtered I have given filter type like,
 filter-type='ddl'

But still I am not getting filtering text box's.only table in getting displayed.. Where I am doing the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `thead` and `tbody`?

```
<table>
<thead>//this is important
<th>Your Header1</th>
<th>Your Header2</th>
</thead>
<tbody>//and this
<tr><td>value1</td></tr>
<tr><td>value2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `theader` is not valid, try `thead`